# table date time compare to date now in sql query?

Tags: php, sql

in my table column `datecreated` the value is `2012-12-04 00:29:30`
I would like to compare it to the `date now` with the format of `d/m/Y`
something like this:

```
$date = date('d/m/y');
$sql = mysql_query("Select * from `tblname` where `datecreated` > '".$date."' ");
```

but I think not working
any help that could make it?
thanks
..

Comment: `but I think not working` Why not just try it out?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [DATE_FORMAT function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to format your column

```
"Select *, DATE_FORMAT(`datecreated`, '%e/%c/%Y') AS `datecreated` from `tblname` where `datecreated` > '$date'"
```